# Material Design ripple effect on other element than button

Tags: angular-material, material-design

I wonder, would it be possible to reuse the Material Design CSS ripple effect on other HTML element than button, for example a div? Or would it be easier to create own ripple effect in CSS?

Comment: Yes, they have a ripple-component that can be used out of the box.
Example: 
<div matRipple [matRippleColor]="myColor">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>

Reference: https://material.angular.io/components/ripple/overview

Comment: @LordSilvermort Thank you, if you create an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Material Design provides a ripple component out of the box, it can be used like this:

In .ts file:

```
import {MatRippleModule} from '@angular/material/core';
```

In view:

```
<div matRipple [matRippleColor]="myColor"> 
 <ng-content></ng-content> 
</div>
```

Examples and more information about the component can be found here: https://material.angular.io/components/ripple/overview